# Integration By Parts on a Fourier Transform

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, fourier-analysis

I'm having trouble with the "An integration by parts in $x$ for the first summand...and the assumption that $\phi$ goes to $0$ as $|x|\to\infty$." 
I tried the integration by parts but ended up with $0$, also, could someone explain the assumption for me? Are we assuming that for the benefit of the question or is there a reason?

The original PDE was $\partial u/\partial x + \partial u/\partial y = u$, and I'd solved it in an earlier assignment by change of variable, yielding the solution $u=e^{y-|x-y|}$. The question asks of me to derive that solution using the Fourier Transform method.

[image: Partial Differential Equations]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $A>0$ $$\int_{-A}^Ae^{i\xi x}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\,dx=
\left(e^{i\xi A}\phi(A,y)-e^{-i\xi A}\phi(-A,y)\right)-i\xi\int_{-A}^Ae^{i\xi x}\phi(x,y)\,dx$$

Now let $A\to\infty$.